# (Should be simple) Adding to Swift dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

So for some reason I can't do this... Been coding for years, Swift since it was released and somehow this has never been a problem. Am I missing something?

```
var categories: [Int : Category] = [:]
```

Now I can't do something like `categories.setObject()` and even doing `categories[0] = Category()` still doesn't create that element in the dictionary, however doesn't throw any errors either.

You can do this example even with a simple `var dict: [String : String] = [:]`

Note: I realise this might be a brutally simple question but I've done my digging... I'm not just posting here because I'm lazy to do the research. haha

**EDIT**

Category definition

```
struct Category {
    var id: Int!
    var name: String!
}
```

Super simple...

Comment: setObject() is accessible to Dynamic type of Dictionary. I think its available only to NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: This _does_ work for me: `var dict: [String: String] = [:]; dict["One"] = "1"; print(dict) // Prints ["One": "1"]`

Comment: @AntonBronnikov hmm... Just to be sure - you're on Swift2 right?

Comment: Yes.  It's "Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 3ebdbb2c7e, Clang f66c5bb67b, Swift 42591f7cba)" to be precise.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov haha precise indeed... ok thanks... Must be something up with my side then

Comment: Does your `Category` have failable initializer?  Can it be that `Category()` simply returns `nil`?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov: good point. @ByronCoetsee please show us how `Category` is defined.

Comment: @ByronCoetsee: can you show a screenshot of your playground where you add a `Category` to your dictionary and it does remain empty?

Comment: @ByronCoetsee, ok.  Then how do you know that "doing categories[0] = Category() still doesn't create that element in the dictionary"?  How do the establish that?  Do you print `categories[0]` to the console, or is it that you just try to inspect it in the debugger at a breakpoint?  Reason I ask is that I noticed that sometimes values reported in the debugger are not what is printed out to console.  No idea why.  Could be some bug in XCode.

Comment: BTW, if in the debugger then you can do `po categories[0]` command to print the value out.

Comment: @ByronCoetsee: did you have a chance to look at the answers we posted for your question?

Comment: @appzYourLife I used a work around for a while and when I went back to test it again, it worked... However I never removed the old code - I simply commented it out so nothing actually changed. I have no idea. Maybe it was trying all the answers that I must have fixed it somehow... How should I mark the answers? Upvote each? I'll mark the closest one as correct I guess, except they all are... haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is very simple indeed

Let's see

> and even doing categories[0] = Category() still doesn't create that element in the dictionary, however doesn't throw any errors either.

In my playground this code does work fine and the `Category` value is properly created.

```
struct Category {
    init() {
        print("init Category")
    }
}

var categories: [Int : Category] = [:]
categories[0] = Category()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly well...

```
struct Category {
    var id: Int!
    var name: String!
}
var categories: [Int : Category] = [:] // [:]
categories[0] = Category() // Category
print("\(categories)") // "[0: Category(id: nil, name: nil)]\n"
```

How are you checking the existence? You have used `!` in your properties, and then not provided values for them - that may be the problem.